# How to add JPanel in a JFrame that is a BufferedImage()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So far I have this:
[image]

The logic is that:

a.)I will press the keybutton 'S' then the game will start

b.)The JTextArea will show the conversation of the users(note: I didn't disable it for debugging purposes)

c.)The JTextField will be the field the user will type text.

I have these working code:

```
package game;

//import 


public class Game extends JFrame {


public static final String SERVER_IP = "localhost";


public static final int WIDTH = 1200;
public static final int HEIGHT = 800;
public static final int SCALE = 1;


private final int FPS = 60;
private final long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

private BufferedImage backBuffer;

public KeyboardInput input;
private Stage stage;

public String username = "";

public GameClient client;
public static Game game;

public static String message = "";

private Tank tank;

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

public Game() throws HeadlessException {
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    addWindowListener(new WinListener());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    //setUndecorated(false);
    addKeyListener(input);
    setVisible(true);
}    
public void init() {
    this.game = this;
    input = new KeyboardInput();

    //this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    //this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //this.setResizable(false);


  Dimension expectedDimension = new Dimension(900, 50);
  Dimension expectedDimension2 = new Dimension(100, 50);
   jButton1 = new JButton("jButton1");

jTextArea1 = new JTextArea(6,6);
jTextArea1.setBounds(0,200,200,200);
jTextArea1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
//jTextArea1.setFocusable(false);
jTextField1 = new JTextField("jTextField1");
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
panel2.add(jTextField1);
panel2.add(jButton1);
panel2.setBackground(Color.BLACK); // for debug only
panel2.setPreferredSize(expectedDimension);
panel2.setMaximumSize(expectedDimension);
panel2.setMinimumSize(expectedDimension);
jPanel1 = new JPanel();
jPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
jPanel1.add(jTextArea1);
jPanel1.add(panel2);
jPanel1.setBackground(Color.RED); // for debug only
jPanel1.setPreferredSize(expectedDimension2);
jPanel1.setMaximumSize(expectedDimension2);
jPanel1.setMinimumSize(expectedDimension2);
jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jPanel1,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
setContentPane(jScrollPane1);

System.out.println("init");
revalidate();

    client = new GameClient(SERVER_IP, this);

    backBuffer = new BufferedImage(800* SCALE,600 * SCALE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
}

public Stage getStage() {
    return stage;
}

public class WinListener extends WindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        disconnect();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}


public void disconnect() {
    Packet01Disconnect p = new Packet01Disconnect(username);
    p.writeData(client);
    client.closeSocket();
    System.exit(0);
}

private Font font = new Font("Munro Small", Font.PLAIN, 96);
private Font font2 = new Font("Munro Small", Font.PLAIN, 50);
private Font fontError = new Font("Munro Small", Font.PLAIN, 25);
private int op = 0;


public void updateMenu() {
    if (input.up.isPressed()) {
        if (op == 1) {
            op = 0;
        } else {
            op++;
        }
        input.up.toggle(false);
    } else if (input.down.isPressed()) {
        if (op == 0) {
            op = 1;
        } else {
            op--;
        }
        input.down.toggle(false);
    } else if (input.enter.isPressed() && op == 0) {
        runningMenu = false;
        input.enter.toggle(false);
    } else if (input.enter.isPressed() && op == 1) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


public void drawMenu() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();
    bbg.setFont(font);
    bbg.setColor(Color.white);

    bbg.drawString("Sample", 189, 180);
    bbg.setFont(font2);
    if (op == 0) {
        bbg.setColor(Color.red);
        bbg.drawString("Start", 327, 378);
        bbg.setColor(Color.white);
        bbg.drawString("Quit", 342, 425);
    } else if (op == 1) {
        bbg.setColor(Color.white);
        bbg.drawString("Start", 327, 378);
        bbg.setColor(Color.red);
        bbg.drawString("Quit", 342, 425);
    }

    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
}

public void draw() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();
    bbg.setColor(Color.black);
    bbg.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    stage.drawStage(bbg, this);
    for (Tank t : stage.getPlayers()) {
        t.draw(bbg, SCALE, this);
    }
    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
}


public void update() {

    tank.update(stage);

    stage.update();
}

private long time = 0;


public void updateLogin() {
    if (username.length() < 8) {
        if (input.letter.isPressed()) {
            username += (char) input.letter.getKeyCode();
            input.letter.toggle(false);
        }
    }

    if (input.erase.isPressed() && username.length() > 0) {
        username = username.substring(0, username.length() - 1);
        input.erase.toggle(false);
    }

    if (input.enter.isPressed() && username.length() > 0) {
        input.enter.toggle(false);
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Packet00Login packet = new Packet00Login(username, 0, 0, 0); 
        packet.writeData(client);
    }

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("connect server success")) {
        time = 0;
        runningLogin = false;
        return;
    }

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Username already exists")) {
        drawLogin();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        message = "";
        username = "";
        time = 0;
    }

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Server full")) {
        drawLogin();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (time != 0 && message.equals("") && (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) >= 5000) {
        message = "cannot connect to the server";
        drawLogin();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        message = "";
        time = 0;
    }
}


public void drawLogin() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();
    bbg.setColor(Color.black);
    bbg.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    bbg.setColor(Color.red);
    bbg.setFont(fontError);
    bbg.drawString(message, 100, 100);
    bbg.setFont(font2);
    bbg.setColor(Color.white);
    bbg.drawString("Username", 284, 254);
    bbg.setColor(Color.red);
    bbg.drawString(username, 284, 304);
    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
}


public static String waitPlayers = "Waiting for others players";
public String auxWaitPlayers = waitPlayers;
public static int quantPlayers = 0;

public class StringWait extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                waitPlayers = "waiting  for  others  players";
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                waitPlayers = "waiting  for  others  players.";
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                waitPlayers = "waiting  for  others  players..";
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                waitPlayers = "waiting  for  others  players...";
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}


public void updateWaitPlayers() {
    if (quantPlayers == 1) {
        runningWaitPlayer = false;
    }
}


public void drawWaitPlayers() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();
    bbg.setColor(Color.black);
    bbg.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    bbg.setColor(Color.white);
    bbg.setFont(fontError);
    bbg.drawString(waitPlayers, 100, 100);
    g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
}

public boolean runningMenu = true, runningLogin = true, runningWaitPlayer = true, runningGame = true;

public int op2 = 0;


public void start() {
    long start;
    long elapsed;
    long wait;
    init();
    while (true) {
        runningGame = true;
        runningMenu = true;
        runningWaitPlayer = true;
        runningLogin = true;
        switch (op2) {
            //..
    }
}


public void setGameState(boolean state) {
   //...
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Game g = new Game();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    g.start();
}
```

}

And these is my objective interface:[image]

I hope someone will help me with my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Set the "main" containers layout manager to `BorderLayout`
- On to this, add the `GameInterface` in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position
- Create another ("interaction") container and set it's layout manager to `BorderLayout`, add this to the "main" container's `BorderLayout.SOUTH` position
- Wrap the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane` and add it to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position of your "interaction" container
- Create another container ("message"), this could use a `GridBagLayout`.  On to this add the `JTextField` (with `GridBagConstraints#weightx` set to `0` and `GridBagConstraints#weightx` set to `1`) and add the button to the next cell (`GridBagConstraints#gridx` set to `1` and `GridBagConstraints#weightx` set to `0`)

For more details, see:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)
- [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

**Note:**

`Graphics g = getGraphics();` is NOT how custom painting should be done. Instead, override the `paintComponent` of a component like `JPanel` and perform your custom painting there!

For more details see

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

**Example**

[image: Test layout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JPanel master = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                master.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

                JPanel gameInterface = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(400, 400);
                    }
                };
                gameInterface.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

                master.add(gameInterface);

                JPanel interactions = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                interactions.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(5, 20)));

                JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
                JButton btn = new JButton("Button");

                JPanel message = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                message.add(field, gbc);
                gbc.gridx = 1;
                gbc.weightx = 0;
                message.add(btn, gbc);

                interactions.add(message, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                master.add(interactions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(master);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you can help me implement it to code? sorry I am new in Java and my native language is C. I am trying to understand your concept, but mostly i don't know how to manipulate interface in java.

Comment: The major problem you're having is the use of `getGraphics`, this is not how to perform custom painting, look at the last two links for more details

Comment: What will i choose to define in the method? The Graphics g = getGraphics(); or the Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics(); ? And how will I call it ?

Comment: Painting is not done this way.  You need to insert yourself into the paint chain and will be told when painting needs to be done.  See the last two links which describe the paint process and how to do custom painting

Comment: How can I change the 'this' for example in g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);? and how will I call drawImage()?

Comment: JPanel implements ImageObserver and is generally recommended when using drawImage, as I can generate repaint events if the image state changes (usually because it's fully loaded). I think you might need to go back to OO basics first